# How to set UserDefaults with XCUItest

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, xcuitest

I am doing iOS UI testing with XCUITest.
Since we do not have access to the app, how do we set defaults to the app?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass all the required data using launch arguments.

Please read documentation

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/1500477-launcharguments

The other (and a bit slower) option is to use deep links.

Comment: the launch arguments cannot work for me. Besides deep links and launch arguments, is there no other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds much more complex than it is, but a technique that has worked for me is to set up an HTTP server in the testing suite that you can use to fetch mock data in your test code. I have had success with [Embassy and Ambassador](https://envoy.engineering/embedded-web-server-for-ios-ui-testing-8ff3cef513df).

So you'd pass in a launch argument telling your app code to fetch from the server. For the case of UserDefaults a helper class for making these specific requests to the local endpoint works well. This unfortunately means your app code has to be doing some setup for testing, but depending on your needs it could be a good compromise.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution to crossing the process boundary:

If you are not doing on device testing, you can access "SIMULATOR_SHARED_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY" and provide the data in a file for your test to consume.

On a real device this would be more difficult because you would need to use a shared Group container.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can use "Application Data Package". It's when you save your app state into a container and then run tests with the saved environment. 
There are many guides how to do it, that's just one of them:

https://www.codementor.io/paulzabelin/xcode-app-data-suni6p4ma

It might me a more powerful and overcomplicated thing that you need, but opens a big world of possibilities ;)